# How can I convert my Bitcoin to Western Union urgently?

Tags: exchanges

I tried posting in some forums but got no replies.

Is there any reputable exchanger out there that can send me Western Union transaction for my Bitcoins? It's not a big amount and I don't mind paying fees to both exchanger and the Western Union.

Comment: Many of the 419 scams (Nigerian Prince, distressed treasure, import scams, etc) are fully willing to just take your bitcoins, you don't need to convert them using Western Union.  If your scammer isn't willing to take bitcoins, find another scammer.

Answer (score 7):

There are many Bitcoin buyers on LocalBitcoin who are willing to pay via Western Union. Look for someone with a very high feedback rating and do not release the Bitcoins from escrow until you are sure the payment you have received is final.

https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/western-union/

Answer (score 1):

A few sites and forums have professional traders and they would offer you this service. Fees is generally lower than fiat transfer through WU.